# Abbreviating several functions - guidelines?

Tags: python, function

This is probably a really dumb question but I will ask anyway.

There are two ways to present this code:

```
file = "picture.jpg"
pic = makePicture(file)
show(pic)
```

or

```
show(makePicture("picture.jpg"))
```

This is just an example of how it can be abbreviated and I have seen it with other functions. But it always confuses me when I need to do it. Is there any rule of thumb when combining functions like this? It seems to me you work backwards picking out the functions as you go and ending with either the file or the function that chooses the file (i.e `pickAFile()`). Does this sound right?

Please keep explanations simple enough that a smart dog could understand.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  The rule for the second one is "work from the inside out" --- things in the deepest parentheses are evaluated first, and so on out to the outermost level.  That exactly parallels what you do in the first case.  (Also, you are missing a closing parenthesis in your second example.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking at all @Danrex.

Comment: In any case, avoid naming a variable `file`, as this is a built-in Python class. :)

Comment: I know they are the same. I am wondering what rule or rules I need to follow when trying to combine other functions in a similar way as it is combined in the second example.

Comment: You never *need* to do it.  Are you asking when it's a good idea to do it, or are you asking how to do it (i.e., how to "translate" your first form into the second form)?

Comment: @Danrex Both pieces of code have the same effect. There are no rules on when you *have* to do so, it's a stylistic choice.

Comment: +1 to this question, because style does matter (for legibility, and therefore maintenance and feature additions).

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear. What I am asking for is the rules of thumb for abbreviating other future functions in the same way that the first function was abbreviated in the second example I gave. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Danrex: "Abbreviated" is not a standard way of referring to what matters here. Most people would think of it as to when temporary variables should be used.

Comment: I'm asking what BrenBarn said. How to translate the first form to the second form but was struggling to find the right way to say it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
pic = makePicture(file)
```

You call `makePicture` with `file` as its argument and put the output of that function into the variable `pic`. If all you do with `pic` is use it as an argument to `show`, you don't really need to use `pic` at all. It's just a temporary variable. Your second example does just that and passes the output of `makePicture(file)` directly as the first argument to `show`, without using a temporary variable like `pic`.

Now, if you're using `pic` somewhere else, there's really no way to get around using it. If you don't reuse the temporary variables, pick whatever way you like. Just make sure it's readable.

Comment: This makes sense and a really clear explanation. But I guess I was wondering more if I was to abbreviate other functions in the future (in a similar way the first function was abbreviated in the second) was there some general rule of thumb I would follow.

Comment: @Danrex: It's not abbreviated. It's just not using a temporary variable.

Comment: I just don't know how else to say it.

Comment: @Danrex: It's not that you're saying it wrong, it's just that you seem to be thinking about it the wrong way. The only difference between them is a temporary variable. You should ask yourself: why would I need to use one here?

Comment: I understand that. So that part makes sense. But I am more interested in how to transform the first code into the second that is translatable to other functions as well.

Answer (score 4):

Chiming in, because I think that style does matter. I would definitely pick `show(makePicture("picture.jpg"))` if you don't ever reuse `"picture.jpg"` and `makePicture(…)`. The reason are that:

- This is perfectly **legible**.
- This makes the code **faster to read** (*no need* to spend more time than needed on it).
- If you use variables, you are sending a signal to people reading the code (including you, after some time) that the variables are *reused* somewhere in the code and that they should better be put in their working (short-term) memory. [Our short-term memory is limited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-term_memory) (in the 1960s, experiments have shown that **one remembers about 7 pieces of information at a time**, and some modern experiments came up with lower numbers). So, if **the variables are not reused** anywhere, they often should be removed so as to not pollute the reader's short-term memory.

I think that your question is very valid and that you *should* definitely not use intermediate variables here unless they are *necessary* (because they are reused, or because they help break a complex expression in directly intelligible parts). This practice will make your code more legible and will give you good habits.

PS: As noted by Blender, having **many nested function calls** can make the code hard to read. If this is the case, I do recommend considering **using intermediate variables** to hold pieces of information that make sense, so that the function calls do not contain too many levels of nesting.

PPS: As noted by pcurry, **nested function calls can also be easily broken down into many lines**, if they become too long, which can make the code about as legible as if using intermediate variables, with the benefit of not using any:

```
print_summary(
    energy=solar_panel.energy_produced(time_of_the_day),
    losses=solar_panel.loss_ratio(),
    output_path="/tmp/out.txt"
)
```

Comment: I would argue against the human memory aspect here. If you use clear variable names, `show(picture)` is self-explanatory and you don't need to skip to the definition of `picture` to figure out what the code does.

Comment: @Blender: I understand what you mean, if you mean that `picture` really does not go into the working memory. I would argue that it actually generally *has* to go there at least partially: the picture is a *specific* picture (e.g. associated to a particular file), and what is specific about it *might* have to be kept in mind; the same question arises for the file name variable. Not using variables completely eliminates this kind of question ("should I remember some details about the contents of the variable, or should I just not care?"), which makes the code faster to parse and more legible.

Comment: I personally find it much harder to glance at a line with many nested function calls and immediately see what it does. For two functions like in your answer, sure, that's perfectly fine, but saying that temporary variables make code harder to read is something that I find hard to believe.

Comment: @Blender: Yeah, too many nested function calls can be hard to read, and I would not necessarily recommend using intermediate variables in this case. I would not say that intermediate variables *necessarily* make the code harder to read. I qualified the answer to address this point.

Comment: PEP8 helps me with nested function calls, as a side effect of complaining about line length.  Breaking `really_long_func_name(long_sub_func(long_arg, sub_func2(long_arg2)))` etc. to under 80 characters per line including indentation can lead to each function call getting one or more line to itself, which clarifies things.

Comment: For simple examples nested function calls are perfectly readable.  There are other times when the nesting can get out of hand, or a temporary variable name can itself be useful documentation that makes the code more readable.  It's something you develop a feel for as you read and write more code (and see BAD examples), and I bet the preference varies from person to person.

Answer (score 1):

It's all at the discretion of the programmer, if you're planning on making a larger program you might want to keep the statements separate so you can refer back to the file.

Readability is always important if you're working with a team of programmers but if this is just something you're doing by yourself, do whatever's most comfortable.

Comment: While I respect this point of view, I must say that I don't agree. `show(makePicture("picture.jpg")` is perfectly readable and does its job; changing it by adding variables just in case one would need to "refer back to the file" makes the code less legible: it is a signal that the file is already needed later in the code; this is an unnecessary burden on the working memory of *anybody* reading the code, including the original author. I also think that even a project done solo should follow practices that work in groups, as it is more efficient to take good habits early.

Answer (score 0):

`show(makePicture("picture.jpg"))` is more readable than the longer version for reasons discussed in other answers.  I have also found that trying to eliminate intermediate variables very often results in a better solution.  However, there are cases where a descriptive naming of a complex intermediate result will make code more readable.